# What Font is Grand St? Good practice to reverse-engineer fonts in General?

Tags: fonts, font-identification

[image]

https://grandst.com/

I'm really attracted to that kind of vintage look.  Does anyone know any similar type fonts that I can play around with?  Is there a good practice to go about understanding what fonts I see in general?  A firefox plugin? A free program?

Thanks in advance for any help you can offer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [WhatTheFont](http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/) to narrow your search.

When that doesn't work (which it doesn't in this case for me), you can post your screen grab here or just go to [the WhatTheFont forum](http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/forum/newcase?imageid=0&string=GrandSt.). I'll place an image of the font in your question and you can use that to further you're query.

Applying an opacity mask in Photoshop or Illustrator will give you that "vintage look" with total control. No need to look for a font with it baked in.

Comment: Another good service for this kind of thing is identifont.com

Answer (score 5):

One of the Grand St. founders here -- The Grand St. font actually doesn't exist.  It was done from scratch by a designer who did our logo typography as well as the logo itself.  The font combines a lot of the style that we as a company wanted our brand to embody.

So glad you like it!

Comment: Did the designer use some specific existing fonts as base or inspiration?

Comment: @svick I'd say American Gothic, according to the answer below!

Answer (score 5):

After searching for a while using both [WhatTheFont](http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/) and [Identifont](http://www.identifont.com/), I found some fonts that come close:

### [Aspirin](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/t26/aspirin/)

[image: "GRAND ST." in Aspirin]

### [American Gothic](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/madtype/american-gothic/)

[image: "GRAND ST." in American Gothic]

### [Barcode](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/fontbureau/barcode/)

[image: "GRAND ST." in Barcode]